# Limit on the Number of Variables for bestglm Function

Tags: r, regression, glm

I am trying to run the `bestglm` function in R for subset selection and the run fails immediately if I use more than 15 variables in the function.  I attached some sample code below (I know these models have far too many variables for this dataset, I am just including these models here as an example):

```
cars.df = data.frame(mtcars)
cars.df
resp.var = cars.df$mpg

ind.matrix.15 = model.matrix(mpg ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb + disp:wt + drat:wt + qsec:am + gear:hp + cyl:disp + drat:gear, data = cars.df)[, -1]
matrix.xy.15 = data.frame(ind.matrix.15, y = as.matrix(resp.var))
bestglm(Xy = matrix.xy.15, family = gaussian(link = 'log'), nvmax = 15)

ind.matrix.16 = model.matrix(mpg ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb + disp:wt + drat:wt + qsec:am + gear:hp + cyl:disp + drat:gear + disp:hp, data = cars.df)[, -1]
matrix.xy.16 = data.frame(ind.matrix.16, y = as.matrix(resp.var))
bestglm(Xy = matrix.xy.16, family = gaussian(link = 'log'), nvmax = 16)
```

The first `bestglm` function runs fine, but when I add an additional variable for a total of 16 features, the second `bestglm` function instantly produces this error message: `p = 16. must be <= 15 for GLM.`

Changing the `method` argument to a simpler algorithm such as `backward` rather than the default `exhaustive` does not make the error go away.

Is this just a limitation of the `bestglm` function, or is there an argument I can change to allow more than 15 features.

Comment: The error message indicates you can fit 15 terms to `bestglm` ([here](https://github.com/cran/bestglm/blob/9a9e26a7fc41dcb3049f0a23d31812faea38e8e2/R/bestglm.R#L196)). I wonder what would changing `RequireFullEnumerationQ` do...

Comment: Interesting, thank you for linking the code.  It looks like the code defaults to the leaps library if the `family = gaussian`, there are no factors with more than 2 levels, and `RequireFullEnumerationQ = FALSE` (default).  If any of those are false, it looks like the function requires 15 or less variables, regardless if `method != exhaustive`.  This is rather unfortunate, but I guess it is just a limitation of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RomanLuštrik says, this is a [hard-coded constraint in bestglm](https://github.com/cran/bestglm/blob/9a9e26a7fc41dcb3049f0a23d31812faea38e8e2/R/bestglm.R#L196), presumably because 15 predictors means there are 2^15 = 32768 candidate models, and one has to stop somewhere ...  as far as I can see there is no way around this constraint when running a GLM. (Roman's suggestion of `RequireFullEnumerationQ=FALSE` doesn't work, because the leaps-and-bound algorithm is only available for linear models, not GLMs.)

One possible strategy (not fully explored here) would be to fit the linear model exhaustively with leaps-and-bounds, save a large number of the top models (say `TopModels=1000`) and then re-evaluate the top models with your preferred variance structure ... this doesn't work directly in `leaps`, but can be hacked as follows:

```
leaps.obj <- leaps:::leaps.setup(matrix.xy.16,y=cars.df$mpg,nvmax=16,
       nbest=10000)
bb <- leaps:::leaps.exhaustive(leaps.obj, really.big=TRUE)
```

but I don't know (and it seems like a lot of work) to figure out how to re-evaluate these models with a log-link Gaussian.

You might be able to get the `glmulti` package to work (it offers both `method="h"` for full enumeration and `method="g"` for a genetic algorithm), but so far I haven't managed to overcome some Java errors ...

Unfortunately, the [J Stat Software article describing glmulti](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i12/v34i12.pdf) shows that this method has some of the same constraints:

> For  performance,  the Java classes  encode  formulas  as  compact  bit  strings.   Currently  two integers (32 bits each) are used for main effects, and two long integers (128 bits) are used for each  category  of  interaction  terms  (factor:factor,  covariate:covariate,  and  factor:covariate),to encode models.  This means that there can be at most 32 factors and 32 covariates, and, if  including  interactions,  at  most  128  interactions  of  each  category.   The  latter  constraint necessitates that, if x is the number of factors and y the number of covariates:
> x <16
> y <16
> xy <128